# setting wifi adapter on ubuntu (mac) without ethernet

Tags: wireless

I was trying to install ubuntu on mac and successfully did so without out impacting mac.Now i don't have ethernet cable and wifi adapter is not available on ubuntu, so it is virtually useless. Is there any clean approach to configure adapters without internet?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a smartphone you can use USB tethering to get internet access. Try googling something like "USB tethering iPhone" and then install the required drivers using the Additional Drivers app.